# Makefile that rebuilds when headers change with libraries

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

So, currently trying to update my Makefile to make .d files so that changes in headers are also caught and recompiled. I've tried a few attempts and I'm running into an error where gcc can't find references to libxml2 functions. By the way, my code compiles, I had a different makefile before that worked fine. Here's the current Makefile:

```
TOP                 = .
SRC_DIR         = $(TOP)/src
INC_DIR         = $(TOP)/include
OBJ_DIR = $(TOP)/_obj
BIN_DIR = $(TOP)/_bin
TARGET          = $(BIN_DIR)/run

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRCS))
DEPS = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.d, $(SRCS))
INCLUDES    = -I$(INC_DIR)

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O3 -g

.PHONY: all clean

EXTRA_INCLUDES = -I/usr/include/libxml2
LIBS = -lm -lxml2
CFLAGS += $(INCLUDES) $(EXTRA_INCLUDES) $(LIBS)

all: $(TARGET)

-include $(DEPS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS) | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -c $< -o $@

$(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    @echo " Cleaning..."
    $(RM) -r $(BIN_DIR)
    $(RM) -r $(OBJ_DIR)
```

Here's the error:

```
mkdir -p _obj
gcc -O3 -g  -I./include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lm -lxml2 -MMD -c src/shellbuilder.c -o _obj/shellbuilder.o
gcc -O3 -g  -I./include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lm -lxml2 -MMD -c src/shellutils.c -o _obj/shellutils.o
mkdir -p _bin
gcc -O3 -g  -I./include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lm -lxml2 -o _bin/run _obj/shellbuilder.o _obj/shellutils.o
/usr/bin/ld: _obj/shellbuilder.o: in function `buildShell':
/_code/mybash/c-proc/src/shellbuilder.c:29: undefined reference to `xmlNodeGetContent'
/usr/bin/ld: _obj/shellbuilder.o: in function `main':
/_code/mybash/c-proc/src/shellbuilder.c:62: undefined reference to `xmlCheckVersion'
/usr/bin/ld: /_code/mybash/c-proc/src/shellbuilder.c:63: undefined reference to `xmlReadFile'
/usr/bin/ld: /_code/mybash/c-proc/src/shellbuilder.c:68: undefined reference to `xmlDocGetRootElement'
/usr/bin/ld: /_code/mybash/c-proc/src/shellbuilder.c:75: undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
/usr/bin/ld: /_code/mybash/c-proc/src/shellbuilder.c:76: undefined reference to `xmlCleanupParser'
/usr/bin/ld: /_code/mybash/c-proc/src/shellbuilder.c:71: undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:43: _bin/run] Error 1
```

Also, I looked into multiple questions that already talked about this and I was curious about the difference between `-MMD`, `-MM`, `-MF` and when to use one versus the other?

Comment: I think this is a dupe of [https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45135). Don't put `LIBS` into `CFLAGS`, but instead place it at the very end of the command.